# How do i compare the ID of my HashMap to my spinner value

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap, android-drawable

So if you see the code below, I have 3 arrays: one stores images, one stores values of my spinner and another stores the hashMap with the values of my images and the values of my spinner.

What I want to do is when I create an image by pressing my button say a husky image shows and when I select husky from my spinner it compares the two id's and if they are the same it will launch any code in the `if` statement.

Comment: What ID? What code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below code snippet to check image view id with hashmap key and spinner text with hashmap value.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private TextView tex_view;

        private Spinner mDogs;
        private ImageView mImageView;
        private Button mButton;
        private Random r;
        private TextView mTextView;
        private TextView mTextView2;

        //image arrays
        final Integer[] images = {R.drawable.home, R.drawable.mobile, R.drawable.sports,
                R.drawable.toys};

        final String[] dogs = {"Select Item", "husky", "kuvasz", "papillon", "vizsla"};

        Map<Integer, String> answers = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{
            put(R.drawable.home, "husky");
            put(R.drawable.mobile, "kuvasz");
            put(R.drawable.sports, "papillon");
            put(R.drawable.toys, "vizsla");
        }};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            tex_view = findViewById(R.id.tex_view);
            mDogs = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic1);
            mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            ArrayAdapter<String> ad1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, dogs);

            mDogs.setAdapter(ad1);

            mDogs.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    if (!mDogs.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select Item")) {
                        String imageID = String.valueOf(mImageView.getTag()); // imageView id
                        String selectedSpinnerText = mDogs.getSelectedItem().toString(); //selected Spinner text
                        for (Object name : answers.keySet()) {
                            String key = name.toString();
                            String value = answers.get(name);
                            if (selectedSpinnerText.equalsIgnoreCase(value) && imageID.equalsIgnoreCase(key)) {
                                tex_view.setText("Both image and Spinner text matches");
                                return;
                            } else {
                                tex_view.setText("Both image and Spinner text not matches");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });

            r = new Random();
            mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //display random images
                    mButton.setText("Next");
                    int pos = r.nextInt(images.length);
                    mImageView.setImageResource(images[pos]);

                    mImageView.setTag(images[pos]);


                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dogapp/com.example.dogapp.Identify_Breed}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: mDogs.setAdapter(ad1);

Comment: please change your contentView layout file name as you need


For example : 

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` - My starting screen xml file name
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_identify__breed);` - I think you have to change this as your need

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked, you can either store the position selected or the id of the image selected:

```
// As a field in your class
private int buttonHuskySelection = -1;

// In your onClick
buttonHuskySelection = images[r.nextInt(images.length)];
mImageView.setImageResource(buttonHuskySelection);
```

Then in the onItemSelected:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (buttonHuskySelection == images[position]) {
        Log.d("TUT", "Found a match!");
    }
}
```